# problem with tab bar, not displaying the tab bar upon navigating to that page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

In my test project I have some 5 tabs on click of a tab it will go to that corresponding class, on click of back in that screen I will come back to my home page but with out the tab bar.. earlier what 5 tabs were there those are not coming ...

following code I am using under back button
where `DataEntry` is the class to where i need to navigate

```
- (void) back_Clicked:(id)sender 
{
     DataEntry *avController;
    UINavigationController *addNavigationController;


    if(avController == nil)
        avController = [[DataEntry alloc] initWithTabBar];

    if(addNavigationController == nil)
        addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:avController];

    [self. navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];

}
```

is I have to add that navigation controller to the tab view? how can I get the tab bar on click of back can any one help me ,thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this, you must already be pushing this view controller either via navigation controller or modally. So the idea would be to simply dismiss it right?

If you have used `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]` then just do `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` . This should take you back to the earlier view controller.

If you have presented this modally like you have done here, you should do `[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return back from a view to the previous view using a back button inside a tab view , i would recommend using a navigation controller inside the view for each tab where you require this functionality. Trying to implement a custom back button without using the navigation controller, in my opinion, is only making things tough for yourself.

If you only want one view to be displayed when you tap on a tab bar button then an ordinary view controller inside the tab bar view should suffice.

The tab bar shouldnt be disappearing altogether unless its been implemented incorrectly.